# Is it good practice to instantiate DI component in presenter class?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, rx-java, dagger-2

I have recently started learning Dagger2. For this purpose I have written an app.

**App Architecture:**

- *ComicListFragment.java* is the main fragment
- This fragment has a presenter that keeps all the logic related stuff in a presenter class called *ComicListFragmentPresenter.java*
- *ComicListFragmentPresenter.java* initializes Dagger2 DI component to inject the required fields.
- *ComicListFragment.java* calls the *ComicListFragmentPresenter.java* public methods to make use of the dependencies & invoking network calls etc.

**Questions:**

- Is it a good practice to instantiate a fragment's dependencies in its Presenter class instead of instantiating the DI component in Fragment and injecting the dependencies through Presenter class constructor & later on accessing those dependencies using getters inside the Fragment class?

Please provide constructive criticism.

Code: https://github.com/wingoku/marvel

Comment: Wouldn't the Presenter be a dependency of the Fragment/Activity? Any Android Framework Class where the instantiation is done by the Framework then 'inject' your component in the hook method and have injected fields. Other than that I prefer constructor injection in pojo classes ...

Comment: @MarkKeen You are correct. Presenter is the dependency of Fragment. But if I make a module for FragmentPresenter then IMO it'll become a mess. If I have 100 fragments, theoratically I will have 200 additional files just to drive that fragment which can very easily get out of control

Comment: All your doing is moving your Activity / Fragment field variables into a module class - if you have common dependencies you can setup your dependency graph with a Component / Subcomponent structure, exposing all common dependencies to the Subcomponents. If you also use constructor injection as long as Dagger can supply the dependencies in the constructor then you don't need to include that class in your module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to instantiate a fragment's dependencies in its Presenter class instead of instantiating the DI component in Fragment and injecting the dependencies through Presenter class constructor & later on accessing those dependencies using getters inside the Fragment class?

No. As in the comment from [Mark Keen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4252352/mark-keen), Fragments, Activities, and Services are chosen as injection targets as they are instantiated by the Android OS and we do not have control over the constructor. The other classes you make should prefer constructor injection for testability so you can swap in test doubles. Furthermore, the new [`dagger.android`](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) library is set up for easy injection with Fragments and Activity so you lose that benefit if you explicitly request injection from a Component inside your Presenter or any other POJO for that matter.

Here's your current Presenter:

```
@Inject
ComicsCacheDBController mComicsCacheDBController;

@Inject
Retrofit mRetrofit;

@Inject
Picasso mPicasso;

/**
 * Instantiate {@link ComicListFragmentPresenter}
 * @param fragment {@link ComicListFragment} instance
 */
public ComicListFragmentPresenter (ComicListFragment fragment)
```

A more testable presenter would just have those dependencies in the constructor (and would perhaps depend on less generic dependencies):

```
@Inject //this is important
public ComicListFragmentPresenter (ComicListFragment fragment, ComicsCacheDBController comicsCacheDBController, Retrofit retrofit, Picasso picasso)
```

Note the `@Inject` annotation on the constructor. It requests Dagger 2 to inject all of those dependencies. If you've configured it correctly, then when you do your field injection inside your Fragment:

```
@Inject ComicsListPresenter comicsListPresenter;
```

The entire object graph for the ComicListPresenter will be injected at the same time.

> If I have 100 fragments, theoretically I will have 200 additional files just to drive that fragment which can very easily get out of control

Dagger 2 and other such dependency injection frameworks help you to solve a specific problem; they make easy to write testable classes by allowing you to pass in dependencies in the constructor that can be swapped for test doubles. For this, the price you pay is having to write lightweight, boilerplate classes. They really suit the ["Uncle Bob"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin) programming style (small classes in lots of little files, strong encapsulation). If you'd rather not have so many small classes and would prefer to group more into one file ([some people](http://number-none.com/blow/john_carmack_on_inlined_code.html) do) then you don't have to use it.

You can get very fast at writing boilerplate if you learn the IDE shortcuts. Write the fields then press <kbd>Cmd+N</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+Ins</kbd> to have Android Studio generate the constructor for you.

Comment: But the reason I have put all the dependencies inside the presenter class is to keep the Fragment class as dumb as possible. All the logic and code to drive the fragment is hidden away in a different class. For instance at some point I want to hook the same functionality with a little modification in a different fragment, I won't have to rewrite all the logic code / copy past the entire code. That's the ONLY reason I have instantiated the DI in presenter and exposed those dependencies using helper methods in the presenter calss

Comment: Are you using the `@Inject` annotations in the dependencies for your presenter? It sounds like you feel you must use the component to perform injection.

Comment: This way is much cleaner indeed. I modified the code it gives me this weird error:

Comment: ```Error:(19, 10) error: fragments.ComicListFragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
fragments.ComicListFragment is injected at
fragments.presenters.ComicListFragmentPresenter.<init>(fragment, …)
fragments.presenters.ComicListFragmentPresenter is injected at
.ComicListFragment.mComicListFragmentPresenter
fragments.ComicListFragment is injected at
interfaces.components.ComicListPresenterComponent.inject(fragment)```

Comment: Okay so you need to study how to write modules for your Fragments: refer to the source code in the Android Architecture Blueprints https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/

Comment: Thanks this repo is very informative. Anyways I just create a separate module and passed ComicListFragment instance to that module which in turns now injects that FragmentInstance in the presenter class. But me passing the fragment instance to presenter class goes against modularity and abstraction I'm trying to achieve. This mistake helped me learn the meaning of that dagger error and how to write even more robust & testable code. Thanks again, you have been very helpful!

Comment: @UmerFarooq okay i'm glad it helped. Thanks for the quick accept.